# Why is my PropertyChanged event firing twice?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, mvvm-light

I'm using wpf, mvvmlight and EF. I have two properties on my entity object which are loosely linked and in my XAML, I would like to have one change when the other changes. Right now, I'm having a problem with the first property changed event firing twice.

My xaml setup is like this, I have DataGrid up top on my xaml, I have my

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MonthlyDonorDetails}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```

The textbox is like,

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding BankCustomerID}"/>
```

Next, in my VM, I load up the data like this,

```
int rowID = 1;
foreach(var row in monthlyDonorsQuery)
{
    row.RowID = rowID++;
    row.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MonthlyDonorDataRow_PropertyChanged);
}

MonthlyDonorDetails = new ObservableCollection<MonthlyDonorFundCode>(monthlyDonorsQuery);
```

This affords me a row id on each row to help user differentiate, and (I'm thinking) allows me to setup a handler for when individual fields change within the row.  Then I set the backing collection for the grid. And this is all working just fine.

NOW, I want to be able to keep two fields in lock-step with each other, an AccountID and an CustomerID.  When the user manually\typing\input changes the AccountID fields, I want to have some code to change the CustomerID, but I don't want this firing needlessly multiple times. Right now its firing twice, and I don't know why? Can anyone see my mistake please?

```
private void MonthlyDonorDataRow_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.PropertyName == "FirstName" || e.PropertyName == "LastName")
        RaisePropertyChanged("DonorName");

    if(e.PropertyName == "AccountID")
    {
        MonthlyDonorFundCode monthlyDonation = sender as MonthlyDonorFundCode;
        int customerID = GetCimsIdFromBankCustomerID(monthlyDonation.AccountID);
        Debug.WriteLine("should be setting to " + customerID);
    }
}
```

When I'm debugging this, all I can see is the EF setter is getting called twice, but I don't know why cause I'm not setting that value. Any help\guidance would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your foreach loop being called twice? If so, you'll have two propery changed event handler registrations.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found out my problem. But it raises another problem for me. I'm calling the method which adds a PropertyChanged handler, twice, while loading. That's another problem I have to figure out.

Thank you Lavr for trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put breakpoint in AccountID setter and look at stack trace then setter is called. You can find "who" updating your property twice.
2. Also you can update AccountID setter like this:

   ```
   private int _accountId;

   public int AccountID
   {
       get { return this._accountId; }
       set 
       {
           if (this._accountId == value) return;
           this._accountId = value;
           this.RisePropertyChanged("AccountID");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you Lavr for answering. My hiccup with setting a backing property is it's coming from Entity Framework. Also, I tried putting a breakpoint in the AccountID but it says [External Code] and I can't see anything before that.  I can TRY to put the breakpoint, but it's in code that is EF generated.  Does this help diagnose things?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with twice invocation of propertychanged. The same thing when I try to catch the extra invoke of the propertychanged, the call stack says it is called from the [External Code]. After I upgraded my Xamarin version from 4.0 to latest (Xamarin 5.0).

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32724964)